# how to add a user created after a OEM installation to a specific group

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, oem

I'm creating an ova template of Ubuntu 18.04 which should be usable for other developers to easily start their own virtual machine on their computer.

Currently I've chosen to use the OEM installation of the ubuntu installer to get the basic system up and running:

- Default packages installed
- Installed "Guest Additions"
- Skel directory setup (major part of default settings are supplied)

As we use sshd a lot, I've added the reconfiguring of open-sshserver to the end of the oem installation:

```
echo "set oem-config/late-command dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server" | debconf-communicate
```

When doing this remove the old keys in the machine by removing them before the final boot.

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/*_key*
```

This basically set the system up just as I want it. Except for the user account that is created. The user should also be in the group `vboxsf`, how do I do this?

Second to that I also want to setup the git config for the user. The user should have the possibility to fill in there email address anywhere during the installation procedure, is this possible? Or is this only possible as a script run at first login or something like that. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.